# Как можно печатать цифры числа по индексу, например как со строками string[0]

Tags: python, int

Хочу запустить такой код но знаю что так нельзя, есть какие то другие способы пройтись над каждым числом с индексом?

```
integer = 123
print(integer[0])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делайте из чисел строки:

```
print(str(integer)[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

превращаем в строку, берём нужный элемент и превращаем в число

```
integer = 123
print(int(str(integer)[0]))
```

можно сделать список

```
integer = list(map(int, str(integer)))
```